# wadofstuff django serializers and manytomanyfields with "through" parameter

Tags: django, serialization, manytomanyfield

With wadofstuff django full serializers v. 1.1.0, I noticed that models with ManyToManyFields that specify a "through" model do not get serialized, even if you specify them explicitly with the relations parameter.

Further, I noticed that serialization of such relations *was* happening in version 1.0.0.

Can anyone verify that this is true, and if so, why this change was made?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this seem to have happened in this changeset https://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/source/detail?r=54

I've wrote a custom serializer based on wadofstuff's that bypasses the field.rel.through._meta.auto_created condition and now models related through other models serialize